# Unresolved external symbol building Python module

Tags: python, c++

I've finally gotten around to getting Python integrated into my program; I've made good progress but I've hit (hopefully) one final snag. I have the following code (inside `python_mgr.cpp`):

```
void say_hello(const char* name)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    def("say_hello", say_hello);
};
```

This works just fine, I am able to build a `hello.pyd` file and import it into the program to be used. However, if I change the contents of `say_hello` to something  else, such as:

```
void say_hello(const char* name)
{
    mandala::app.exit();
}
```

I get the following output from `setup.py`:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'hello' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\boost_1_55_0 -I..\ext\glm-0.9.4.4 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tp../mandala/python_mgr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala/python_mgr.obj
python_mgr.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
c:\python27\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(516) : see previous definition of 'round'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild /EXPORT:inithello build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala/python_mgr.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\hello.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\hello.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\hello.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\hello.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\hello.exp
python_mgr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall mandala::app_t::exit(void)" (?exit@app_t@mandala@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function __catch$?exec@python_mgr_t@mandala@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z$0
python_mgr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct mandala::app_t mandala::app" (?app@mandala@@3Uapp_t@1@A) referenced in function __catch$?exec@python_mgr_t@mandala@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z$0
build\lib.win32-2.7\hello.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have no idea how to resolve this or why the error is happening. For reference, here is my `setup.py` script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name='mandala',
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('hello', ['../mandala/python_mgr.cpp'],
        include_dirs=['C:\\boost_1_55_0', '..\ext\glm-0.9.4.4'],
        library_dirs=['C:\\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib'])
    ])
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting linker errors complaining about:

```
public: void __thiscall mandala::app_t::exit(void)
```

which is your this class pointer, "mandala::app" struct, and exit function.

```
struct mandala::app_t mandala::app
```

Which means the object file, or "module", as python calls it, you compiled, `python_mgr.obj`, does not recognize what this, mandala, app, or exit are,

```
this->mandala::app.exit();
```

because it does not contain the compiled code for your this class, "app" struct and respective "exit" call. (Note that the this call in your case is implicit, but still used.)

You need to add these to your module or compile them into a separate module and link it.